# Class view default view location defaults to wrong folder

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have the following class in my views.py file:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product
```

Which correctly displays view, stored at `products/product_detail.html`

However, i also have the following class in views file:

```
class OfferDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Offer
```

I have created `offer` directory with `offer_detail` view. However, Django still tries to get `products/offer_details.html`

Of course i can manually set template name, but I want Django to search in `offers` folder. Why does it search in `products`?

Comment: That is logical, normally it uses the `app_name/templates/app_name` (so the name of the app, not the name of the models).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django uses the name of your app, so if OfferDetailView is defined inside products, it will search inside that template folder. Model names are not taking into account.